# SSRS: Using expressions to build parameter for sproc

Tags: reporting-services

I have a sproc that takes as an argument a string that lists ids.  The sproc uses dynamic sql to return of a list of records for the ids passed in.  I would like my report to run on Monday with one list, Tuesday with a different list, etc.  Can I build the parameter each day with an expression?

Cheers,

Bill

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82yfs2zh(v=vs.90).aspx) article that explains the WeekDay() function. In SSRS you can use something similar:

```
=Switch
 (
    WeekDay(!Paramters.SomeDate.Value)=1 , "Sunday",
    WeekDay(!Paramters.SomeDate.Value)=2 , "Monday",
    WeekDay(!Paramters.SomeDate.Value)=3 , "Tuesday",
    WeekDay(!Paramters.SomeDate.Value)=4 , "Wednesday",
    ...
    WeekDay(!Paramters.SomeDate.Value)=7 , "Saturday"
  )
```

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of the Weekday function but not the Switch and setting the Parameters like this.  Is this in the body of the report or in the Parameters dialog?

Comment: You could set a default value on the parameter with an expression similar to above.